# vs code: source control shows no changes and infinitely duplicates the same project

Tags: visual-studio-code

vs code: source control shows no changes and infinitely duplicates the same project.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/na3ba.png)

I deleted the .git folder, used the Restart Extension Host command, but nothing worked
vscode is properly updated with the latest version

Comment: are you using GitLens? Please add version info for all the things: OS, VS Code, relevant VS Code extensions.